# adding custom stylesheet to wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, css

im having troubles getting my custom stylesheet work on WP-ADMIN area.
`plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__) );` do i have to create folder in my plugins named css or do i just copy my `.css` to the `wp-admin/css` directory?

i tried both it doesnt seem to work for me.

and what values should be replaced to `__FILE__`?

sorry im kinda new to these stuff.

```
/*ADDS STYLESHEET ON WP-ADMIN*/
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'safely_add_stylesheet_to_admin' );
    function safely_add_stylesheet_to_admin() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__) );
    }


/*ADDS MY CUSTOM NAVIGATION BAR ON WP-ADMIN*/
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_nav');
function custom_nav(){
    include('custom_nav.html');

}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

According to WordPress Codex ([here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)):

> **admin_enqueue_scripts** is the first action hooked into the admin
> scripts actions.

**Example**

Loading a CSS or JS files for all admin area:

```php
//from functions.php

//First solution : one file
//If you're using a child theme you could use:
// get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead of get_template_directory_uri()
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_style' );
function load_admin_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
    //OR
    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
}

//Second solution : two or more files.
//If you're using a child theme you could use:
// get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead of get_template_directory_uri()
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_styles' );
function load_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin_css_foo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style-foo.css', false, '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin_css_bar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style-bar.css', false, '1.0.0' );
}
```

> do i have to create folder in my plugins named css or do i just copy
> my .css to the wp-admin/css directory?

No, put your CSS file together with the other, in your theme directory, then specify the path with:

```
get_template_directory_uri() . '/PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE'
```

For ex my file name is `admin-style.css` and i put it in a folder named `css` my path will looks like:

```
get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin-style.css'
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: may i just ask, if i want to import 3 more stylesheets. do i just add (x3) of this part `wp_register_style( 'admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );` or a separate function?

Comment: `wp_register_style` immediately followed by the related `wp_enqueue_style` (as in 'First solution') is absolutely unncessary and does nothing more/different than just use `wp_enqueue_style` with all params passed to `wp_register_style`.

Comment: Because I'm using a child theme I changed the path function to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

Answer (score 15):

If you want to make CSS changes for the admin panel. paste the below code in functions.php of your child theme

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts'); // admin_head is a hook my_custom_fonts is a function we are adding it to the hook

function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<style>
    #posts-filter table.posts{
        table-layout:auto;   
    }
  </style>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick fix!

Answer (score 2):

For those who want add CSS file in admin area from custom plugin (or plugin's folder):

```
if (is_admin()) {
```

Get src if file in folder:
(..myPluginFolder/myfolder/css/my.css)

```
$myCssFileSrc = plugins_url( '/myfolder/css/my.css', __FILE__ );
```

Get src if file in root plugin folder:
(..myPluginFolder/my.css)

```
$myCssFileSrc = plugins_url( 'my.css', __FILE__ );
```

Enqueue (activate) stylesheet file:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-css', $myCssFileSrc );
} //endif;
```

All manipulation in main plugin file (myplugin.php)

Comment: That's the same approach OP had in the question though didn't it, which mustn't have been working for them?

Comment: The approach used in the question is not correct. I have presented a completely, personally tested, and workable code for connecting a CSS file to the admin part of the site. This is exactly how it is recommended to do it in the documentation for creating plugins: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/determining-plugin-and-content-directories/

Comment: I can confirm the code @tagformat.com provided is workable and is the wordpress codex recommended method provided it is wrapped in a function and you and hook that function to your target enqueue action. Otherwise the css (or if using scripts) the js file is enqueued too soon.