# How To Differentiate Drafted product and Publish Product through Color?

Tags: wp-admin, admin-css

I want to set a different color border for product drafts and published products in my WordPress backend page.

If there is a drafted product in my WordPress product listing page then it should have a red background color and if there is a published product available then it should have a green background color.

Comment: Sorry, I have misread your question. You need backend, my solution is for front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually achieve this using simple CSS. If you look at the HTML you can see that each row has some classes:

```
 <tr class="post-1349 type-page status-draft hentry alternate iedit author-self level-0" id="post-1349">
```

There you can see that there actually is a class that indicates a draft: `status-draft`

So now by simply adding an admin style you can easily style drafts. Just create a css file in `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/admin-style.css` and add this:

```
.status-draft {
  background-color: red;
}
```

...or published posts:

```
.status-publish {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Now you need to add this to your `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_175526_load_admin_style' );
function wpse_175526_load_admin_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse_175526_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
}
```

For details on how you add an admin style please head over to this answer: [adding custom stylesheet to wp-admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110895/adding-custom-stylesheet-to-wp-admin)

Comment: Have you read the link I posted concerning how to add custom admin styles?

Comment: yes...i read those article and also try it but I'm failed to getting success. will you please tell me actually in which file i have to write this php code?

Comment: Yogesh I added some more details.

Comment: add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_175537_load_admin_style' ); in this line what is the meaning of "wpse_175537_load_admin_style".

Comment: there are many functions.php file. so in which folder locations i have to write this code for functions.php?

Comment: I added the path. Keep in mind to replace `your-theme-name` with your actual active themes name. wpse_175526 is just a function name, it stands for WordPress Stack Exchange (this site) and the question number.